# Can I buy a Houston METRO Q Fare Card at the airport?

Tags: trains, tickets, texas, houston, iah

Is it possible to buy a METRO Q Fare card in or near the George Bush International Airport in Houston, Texas?

The [METRO web site](https://www.ridemetro.org/Pages/FareRetailersReloadLocations.aspx) provides a list of retailers which sell these cards, but I don't know how to tell if any of these are in or near the airport.

And the [Route 102 - Bush IAH](https://www.ridemetro.org/MetroPDFs/Schedules/BusSchedules/n102-Bush-IAH-Express.pdf) info sheet doesn't make it any clearer to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the information available on the Ride Metro site and on the list of approved retailers there are none in the airport itself.

The closest retailers that sell the card would be [Kroger Stores](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=kroger&ll=30.030164,-95.336609&spn=0.231249,0.273972&sll=29.981405,-95.352402&sspn=0.231363,0.273972&near=George+Bush+Intercontinental+Airport,+2800+North+Terminal+Road,+Houston,+TX+77032&geocode=CRkO-EJcCoNXFXePyQEdgUFR-inHVUPZI7RAhjExwsDI_LTGnA&hq=kroger&t=m&fll=30.029569,-95.350342&fspn=0.231251,0.273972&z=12&iwloc=A) on US 59 or Treaschwig Rd.

You can probably use the [Zipcode Map](http://www.zipmap.net/Texas.htm) and the [Metro Retailer List by Zip](https://www.ridemetro.org/FareInfo/Pdfs/Web-listing-zip.pdf) to see if there is anything closer but I haven't found anything nor there are any retailers in IAH's zipcode(77032).

Answer (score 4):

As [Karlson's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/23715/47309) mentions, the Metro website does not show any Q Card (reloadable fare card) retailers on the IAH airport property.

However, if you have a U.S. mailing address, you can [request a Q Card by mail](https://www.ridemetro.org/Pages/RequestQCard.aspx) on the Metro website. This could be an option if your trip to Houston is far enough in the future. You can optionally create an online account so that you can top up your card remotely.

Also, since the question was first answered, Metro has added an app for [mobile ticketing](https://www.ridemetro.org/Pages/MobileTicketing.aspx). While you can't purchase a Q Card this way, you could at least buy a day pass that would allow you to travel to a retail location where you could get a Q Card.